# Ajax response text not returning any result in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know ajax is easy to use with jquery, but here I am trying to understand ajax with core javascript, I am sending two values name and age from index.html to indexPhp.php, In console it shows this message  `XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/delPro/indexPhp.php".` but it is not showing any result in div, here is html, js and php script

```
<html>
<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>        

<body>            
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
Age:  <input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br><br>  
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showUser()">Submit</button>
<div id="resultDiv"></div>     
</body>        
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function showUser() {

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "indexPhp.php";   
var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
var age= document.getElementById("age").value;    

var vars = {Name: name, Age: age};

hr.open("POST",url,true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){

        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        alert(hr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = return_data;
    }        
}
  hr.send(vars);

}
```

php script

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['age'])){

echo  $name = $_POST['name'] . " " . $age = $_POST['age'];    

}
```

Comment: The `vars` parameter you use in `hr.send(vars)` should be a string, not an object: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp. That might cause the error. By the way, did you check if you receive something at the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884963/how-to-submit-this-form-using-ajax-without-jquery-but-pure-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the data like this,

```
var vars = "Name="+name+"&Age="+age;
```

In your code you are sending the data as an object.

Comment: yes i did this way also, using this way it's shows values in url

Comment: `hr.open("POST",url,true); 
hr.send(vars);` This won't be displaying the value in the url

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ajax function I made sometimes ago. It can do both post and get and the use is just like you would use jQuery's ajax.

```
function ajax(options, timeout){
    method = options.method || "POST";
    url = options.url || "#";
    (!timeout) ? timeout = 10000 : timeout = timeout * 1000; 
    var request, timedOut = false, xhrTooLong, datas = "";
    try{
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch ( error ) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
        } catch ( error ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(options.data){
        for( dat in options.data){
            (datas == "")?datas+= (method.toLowerCase()=="get"?"?":"")+dat+"="+
               options.data[dat]:datas+="&"+dat+"="+options.data[dat];
        }
    }
    if(method.toLowerCase() == "get" && datas.length > 0)
        url = url + datas;
    request.open(method, url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( request.readyState == 1 ) {
            xhrTooLong = setTimeout(function(){
                if(request.readyState == 1){
                    timedOut = true;
                    request.abort();
                    if(options.aborted) options.aborted(true);
                }
            }, timeout);
        }
        if(request.readyState == 4 && !timedOut){
            window.clearTimeout( xhrTooLong );
            if(options.complete) options.complete (true);
            if ( /200|304/.test( request.status ) ) {
                if(options.success) options.success(request.responseText);
            } else {
                if(options.error) options.error(request.status);
            }
        }
    }
    request.setRequestHeader( 'If-Modified-Since', '06 Oct 1970 00:00:00 GMT' );
    if(method.toLowerCase() == "get"){
        request.send( null );
    } else {
        if(!options.contentType){
            request.setRequestHeader( 'Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' );
        } else {
            request.setRequestHeader( 'Content-type',options.contentType );
        }
        request.setRequestHeader( 'Accepts', '*' );
        request.send( encodeURI( datas ) );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can rewrite showUser like this:

```
function showUser() {

    var url= "indexPhp.php";   
    var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
    var age= document.getElementById("age").value;

    var vars = {Name: name, Age: age};

    ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "post",
        data: vars,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = result;
        },
        error: function(){ alert("Failed!") },
        aborted: function(){ alert("Aborted!") },
        complete: function(){ alert("Complete!") }
    });

}
```

You could also pass in an optional timeout in seconds after closing the function braces in the ajax call.